# Angular 2 - Example Code - Defined Model Property Undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

Trying to follow this example of hooking up a form from the Angular 2 tutorials. I'm adapting the code for a login page.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Here is my model,

```
export class LoginModel {
  constructor(
      public id: number,
      public password: string
  ) {}
}
```

Here is my component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { LoginModel } from "../Models/login.model";

@Component({
   selector: "login-form",
   templateUrl: "views/login.component.html",
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   model = new LoginModel(111, "true");
   submitted = false;

   ngOnInit() {
      this.model.id = 111;
      this.model.password = "true";
   }

   onSubmit(): void {
       this.submitted = true;
   }

   // remove - used for debugging
   get diagnostic(): string {
       return "HERE: " + JSON.stringify(this.model);
   }
}
```

OnInit in the component is probably not needed, just thought I would give it a try.

Finally here is my HTML,

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Login Form</h1>
{{diagnostic}}
<form *ngIf="model">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="id">User ID:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="model.id"
        >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="model.password"       
        >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The error I keep running into is that "model.id" is undefined. To verify this I added *ngIf="model". I'm not sure why the model is showing as undefined here when it is defined in the LoginComponent which is imported through my module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been stuck on this bit for a while and haven't been able to find anything helpful scouring the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have all the code, but I think you may not have all the necessary modules imported. Seems like you are missing `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`

Here is a plunker I created from the code you supplied above and I filled in the blanks for the missing `NgModule` definition: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bNN3h4)

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. I am importing the FormsModule, adding ReactiveFormsModule makes no difference. I think there might just be something fundamentally wrong with the environment that is setup in my visual studio. I'll try to do a clean install / make a new project and see if that resolves anything. Thanks!

Comment: By some miracle I start my computer this morning, decide to give the old project one more try, and it just works. Honestly can't explain why it was failing before besides visual studio being messed up. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it is working.  I have had problems recently in IntelliJ that seem to point back to the IDE's cache since clearing the cache and restarting it seem to force IntelliJ to reindex.